# Should i just buy an Ubuntu CD?

Tags: software-installation

Instead of downloading ubuntu is it more expedient to just purchase an ubuntu cd from an online source?

Answer (score 3):

It totally depends on your internet connection. For most people with a high-speed connection, downloading Ubuntu is relatively fast (though it could take up to a few hours, depending on various factors) and therefore not a problem.

However, if you have a very slow connection or a prohibitive "data cap" on your data plan, you may want to buy an Ubuntu DVD, or a USB drive with Ubuntu pre-loaded on it, instead of downloading it yourself.

Please note that the Ubuntu Desktop installer is too large to fit on a CD, so any optical disc you buy with Ubuntu on it will be a DVD instead.

Comment: For scale, the Ubuntu 16.04 installer is 1.5GB in size. On my home 5Mbps connection, it downloads in about 40 minutes. On my school's 100Mbps connection, it takes less than five minutes.

Answer (score 0):

It's a matter of personal choice and your internet connectivity.It's relatively easy to download the image and burn it to USB than to go and buy a CD (in my personal opinion). If you are on a slow connection then it's always easy to buy a CD.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldnt pay much as it's free. if you do buy it try to buy from ubuntu so the proceeds go to further development of ubuntu further more I belive you can download a minimal .iso and add programs and such as you need them.

Comment: FWIW Canonical doesn't seem to sell a bootable optical disk anymore, just a [USB drive](https://shop.canonical.com/product_info.php?products_id=1206).